# Fragment with multiple Recycler Views freezes UI

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am creating a Fragment that has 5 horizontal recycler views under a vertical Scroll View but each time this fragment needs to be loaded, the UI freezes for about a second.

I have created an Adapter that sets the Data from 2 different POJOs into the different Recycler Views. I have found out that the line from my code which seems to be causing  the issue is the setLayoutManager() because once commented, the fragment loading does not freeze the UI. Apart from that I haven't been able to find out why is that happening when assigning the LayoutManger to the recycler view and what could I do to improve the fragment's performance.

Here is the fragment_home.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.entertainment.logicaldays.planetmovie.views.fragments.HomeFragment"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_popular_movies"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_upcoming_movies"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_top_rated_movies"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_popular_tv_shows"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_top_rated_tv_shows"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then I have the recycler_item.xml to bind to the Recycler Views:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/hover_values">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                            android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                            android:id="@+id/recycler_image" />
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="20dp"
                            android:layout_height="20dp"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                            android:alpha="0"
                            android:id="@+id/poster_hover_image"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/star"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                            android:alpha="0"
                            android:id="@+id/poster_hover_text"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@id/poster_hover_image"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/theboldfont"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
                </RelativeLayout>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:minLines="2"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:id="@+id/recycler_title"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The Adapter which can bind 2 different POJOs into the Recycler Views:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    public Object pojo;
    public Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context ctx, Object movies) {
        this.pojo = movies;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        final ValueAnimator animatorPosterTint = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 180);
        final ValueAnimator animatorHoverOpacity = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);

        //When long-pressing the Movie
        view.setOnLongClickListener(new LongClickOnPosterItemListerner(view, animatorPosterTint, animatorHoverOpacity));

        //When releasing the touch on the movie
        view.setOnTouchListener(new ReleasePosterItemListener(view, animatorPosterTint, animatorHoverOpacity));

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(pojo instanceof MovieList) {
            holder.title.setText(((MovieList)pojo).results.get(position).title);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(Utils.BASE_TMDB_POSTER_URL + ((MovieList)pojo).results.get(position).posterPath)
                    .into(holder.image);
            holder.rating.setText(Float.toString(((MovieList)pojo).results.get(position).voteAverage));
        }
        else{
            holder.title.setText(((TVList)pojo).results.get(position).name);
            Glide.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(Utils.BASE_TMDB_POSTER_URL + ((TVList)pojo).results.get(position).posterPath)
                    .into(holder.image);
            holder.rating.setText(Float.toString(((TVList)pojo).results.get(position).voteAverage));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int count = 0;

        if(pojo instanceof MovieList && ((MovieList)pojo).results != null) {
            if (((MovieList)pojo).results != null) {
                count = ((MovieList)pojo).results.size();
            }
        }
        else{
            if (((TVList)pojo).results != null) {
                count = ((TVList)pojo).results.size();
            }
        }

        return count;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        ImageView image;
        TextView title;
        TextView rating;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_image);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_title);
            rating = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster_hover_text);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally we have the HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    public MainActivity mainActivity;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_popular_movies)
    RecyclerView recyclerPopularMovies;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_upcoming_movies)
    RecyclerView recyclerUpcomingMovies;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_top_rated_movies)
    RecyclerView recyclerTopRatedMovies;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_popular_tv_shows)
    RecyclerView recyclerPopularTVShows;

    @BindView(R.id.recycler_top_rated_tv_shows)
    RecyclerView recyclerTopRatedTVShows;

    @BindView(R.id.view_pager)
    ViewPager viewPager;

    LinkedHashMap<Utils.RequestsToLoad, Boolean> requestsToLoad;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mainActivity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

        // Inflate the layout into the Fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);

        startViewPager();
        startRecyclerViews();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void startRecyclerViews(){
        displayRecyclerView(recyclerPopularMovies, mainActivity.popularMovies);
        displayRecyclerView(recyclerTopRatedMovies, mainActivity.upcomingMovies);
        displayRecyclerView(recyclerUpcomingMovies, mainActivity.topRatedMovies);
        displayRecyclerView(recyclerPopularTVShows, mainActivity.popularTVShow);
        displayRecyclerView(recyclerTopRatedTVShows, mainActivity.topRatedTVShow);
    }

    private void displayRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView, Object object){
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mainActivity, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), object);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    }

    private void startViewPager(){
        SwipeAdapter swipeAdapter = new SwipeAdapter(getActivity(), mainActivity.upcomingMovies);
        viewPager.setAdapter(swipeAdapter);
    }

}
```

As said before, is there anything that could be causing that delay to load the fragment so that I can improve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try adding a Progress Bar till the RecyclerView gets inflated with all data in its views,see if this helps

Comment: That is one of the options I had in mind but I'd like to avoid it if possible. I did not think 5 recycler views (with 20 items each) could make the UI freeze when performing the fragment replacement.

Comment: It may not be due to the Freeze caused by UI Elements,rather due to the Thread trying to fetch all the items and set data to all the views,besides its a good practice to do a loading screen to load all the items for a recyclerview,esp if its from an API

Comment: It was due because of the complexity of the Item layout, after optimizing the layout hierarchy from my recycler_item.xml the amount of time the UI was frozen has drastically decreased.

Comment: Instead of adding recyclerview in scrollview, you can directly add all horizontal recyclerview in vertical recyclerview adapter.